# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'

Tags: jinja2

I removed an if statement within the for statement and now I have this endlock error that is clearly there... I checked some other posts on here and I think my indentation is correct and I dont have any extra spacing... Im not sure what it could be...

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Users <small>Admin {{session.username}}</small></h1>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/add_user"> Add User</a>
<hr />
<table class="table users">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
        <td><a href="edit_user/{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right">EDIT</a></td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{url_for('edit_user', id=user.id)}}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="post" />
                <input type="submit" value="DELETE" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any problem with your code, but i guess you need to disable cache and force reloading templates:

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

refer to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=templates_auto_reload#flask.Flask.templates_auto_reload

let me know if it works.